# Android SQLite Error Caused By getWriteableDatabase()

Tags: android, sqlite

I am fairly new to Android and am trying to create a database which contains a table to store an email address, username and password. After applying break points to the program the following line of code appears to be throwing up issues:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWriteableDatabase();
```

Here is the code which surrounds the line above:

```
// Create A User
public boolean createUser(String userEmail, String userName, String userPassword) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_USER_EMAIL, userEmail);
    values.put(KEY_USER_NAME, userName);
    values.put(KEY_USER_PASSWORD, userPassword);

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    database.close();
}
```

When attempting to create a user I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3052)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3519)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14140)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3047)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3519)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14140)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.pastpapercreator.chemistrypastpapercreator/databases/chemistryPastPaperCreator (conn# 0) already closed
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2088)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:690)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:176)
            at com.pastpapercreator.chemistrypastpapercreator.helper.DatabaseHelper.createUser(DatabaseHelper.java:111)
            at com.pastpapercreator.chemistrypastpapercreator.CreateAccount.createAccount(CreateAccount.java:83)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3047)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3519)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14140)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code used to create the database:

```
// User Table Column Names
private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "uId";
private static final String KEY_USER_EMAIL = "uEmail";
private static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "uName";
private static final String KEY_USER_PASSWORD = "uPassword";

// User Table Creation Statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER +
"(" + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Create Required Tables
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);

        database.close();
    }
```

Comment: You likely have a bug in your lifecycle callbacks such as database helper `onCreate()`. Please post those.

Comment: show you database handler method implementation... you are not initialising it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this on your database helper class
Check your Crete query

```
// Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
  + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
  + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
  + " text not null);";

   public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
  database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, figured out from your example above that I was closing the database in the onCreate() method when I shouldn't be. After removing that statement the app works fine now.